# QGIS Processing Toolbox disappeared

Tags: qgis

Suddenly the button for opening the toolbox is gone. I have searched really long already. 
Do you have any idea how to get it back?

[image: no possibility to enter the toolbox]

Comment: Do you mean the Processing toolbox? It is a plugin that you might have to enable with the menu Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins menu.

Comment: You are right! :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you mean the Processing toolbox? It is a plugin that you might have to enable with the menu Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins menu.